# SharePoint - Open New Document

Tags: library, content, document

I have a document library with two content types, each having a default template. I want to use the "New" drop down menu to open these templates and create documents. When Microsoft Word is running these templates, when clicked, open with no problem however when Microsoft Word is not running nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to fix this so the documents open without word already running prior.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Hello. This isn't a programming question, so you may have better luck on [sharepoint.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this just an problem with your client machine.  Try another PC if you have access, and also get someone else to try.  This should indicate whether it's a user problem, machine problem or server problem. Otherwise, go through the standard steps... (check after each step)

Clear IE cache

Reboot

Clear user profile

Reinstall Office

Reinstall IE

Rebuild PC